# Фреймворки для Java

Tags: jsp, jdbc, java

Добрый день.

Хотел поинтересоваться, с чего начать, что бы написать простое Web - приложение на Java ?

Просто когда интересовался этим вопросом, то даже не понял с чего начать. Все советуют разные фреймворки, разные названия а я в этом пока что не разбираюсь. Желательно также подсказать что то подобное, связанное с базой данных.

Comment: Здесь вам посоветуют "разные фреймворки, разные названия". А вы в этом не разбираетесь, с ваших же слов. Так на что вы надеетесь? Может посмотрите на то, что вам уже посоветовали?

Comment: Я имею в виду с чего начать ? Куча разных названий и абсолютно непонятно с чего можно начать , а что нужно изучать имея какой то багаж знаний

Answer (score 2):

Ну нет начинать с framework'ов не стоит.

Надо начинать с базы (понятно что слово java вы уже должны знать - типы данных, коллекции, потоки...):

1) Контейнер Servlet'ов

2) JSP, jstl

3) Вот после этого можно framework'и

В качестве сервера приложений лучше всего tomcat использовать, он чаще всех (из OpenSource AppServer'ов) в enterprise применяется.

Ну и перед всем этим вам нужно уверенно владеть HTTP (коды ответов, заголовки, кеширование, редиректы, команды: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, наконец по telnet HTTP уметь слать)

База - наверное самый хороший вариант на первое время это H2 (ненужна установка, достаточно просто подключить драйвер и jdbs url указать)

Comment: >В качестве сервера приложений лучше всего tomcat
Tomcat не реализует всей EE спецификации и не может считаться апликейшн сервером.
Например Tomcat входит в состав JBoss только в качестве веб-контейнера.

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что вспомнилось:

1. [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) — проще некуда, как мне кажется: конфигурирование посредством аннотаций, отсутствие XML-конфигов и длительного конфигурирования POM (maven), быстрый старт. Мне показалось пока ещё сыроватым, но для обучения или чего-то не сложного — сойдёт. Куча сэмплов, отличная документация, масса книг и статей.
2. [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) — довольно низкий порог входа, простое обучение, но использовать для чего-то серьёзного я бы не стал.

Comment: Скажите, а вот JSP вы бы посоветовали бы начинающему ? Т.к. я понял что веб приложения можно делать и с помощью его.

Comment: можно начинать и с jsp так как там тоже сложно мало особенно в начале. страница это микс из джава кода и html. как вариант можно сервлеты + чистый `html+js`

Answer (score 0):

Быстрое приложение можно создать на [Spring Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/)

Spring Roo позволяет быстро создать скелет приложения и уже модифицировать его по своему усмотрению. Необходиы начальные знания Spring.

Пример создания на главной странице [проекта](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/)

Answer (score 0):

Мой ответ прост:
JSF + Hibernate

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой фреймворк для Java веб это [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/) - он не утяжелен всякими изысками как тот же Spring и в то же самое время достаточно мощный.

Касаемо БД - надо смотреть на де-факто промышленный стандарт [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) - это из разряда *must know*

Связка Struts-Hibernate - нормальная работоспособная промышленная вещь. Много где применяется.

**Update**

К дискуссии, в частности [[@Drylozav](/users/12293/drylozav)](/users/12293/drylozav) пишет:

> Скажите, а вот JSP вы бы посоветовали бы начинающему ? Т.к. я понял что веб 
> приложения можно делать и с помощью его.

JSP/Servlet это как бы строительные блоки. JSP более высокого уровня чем Servlet. Если Servlet условно говоря это кирпичики, то JSP это как бы стеновые блоки, а фреймворк это архитектурная концепция.

Скажем:

- в основе Spring лежит концепция [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (и не только);
- в основе Struts лежит простейшая реализация концепции [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller);
- Hibernate реализует концепцию POJO (Persistent Object Java Object или Plain Old Java Object) - по сути в понимании Hibernate SQL таблица соответствует Java классу, а запись в ней Java объекту/бину;
- и т.д.

Грубо говоря, как бы ты ни писал - то все равно вынужден будешь следовать концепции заложенной в основу выбранного фреймворка - в этом суть использования фреймворка.